# Jupyter Notebook doesn't show in Dashboard (Windows 10)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

My Jupyter Notebook doesn't show in the Jupyter Dashboard in Windows 10.

Additionally, I get the following error in my Jupyter cmd line console:

[W 00:19:39.638 NotebookApp] C:\Users\danie\Documents\Courses\Python-Data-Science-and-Machine-Learning-Bootcamp Jupyter Notebooks\Python-Data-Science-and-Machine-Learning-Bootcamp\Machine Learning Sections\Decision-Trees-and-Random-Forests\Decision Trees and Random Forest Project - Solutions.ipynb doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

The files path names are too long.  Reducing the path length by reducing the number of folders and/or folder name lengths will solve the problem.